# манипулирование URL в Retrofit фрагментом JSON ответа

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Имеется фейковый апи по адресу: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos
Как мне выхватить данные только одного блока, например:

```
{
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "officia porro iure quia iusto qui ipsa ut modi",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/24f355",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/24f355"
 },
```

Мой код:

```
public interface Api {
    @GET("photos")
    Call<List<Model>> galleryContent();
}

public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = 
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        }
    return retrofit;
    }
}

public class Model {
    private String albumId;
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String url;
    private String thumbnailUrl;

    public String getAlbumId() {
        return albumId;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }
}

public class QRActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
    TextView textView;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_qr);

        loadData();
        textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
    }

public void loadData() {
        Api api = ApiClient.getClient().create(Api.class);
        Call<List<Model>> gallery = api.galleryContent();
            gallery.enqueue(new Callback<List<Model>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Model>> call, Response<List<Model>> 
response) {

            if (response.body() != null && response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.i("test", "onResponse: " + response.body().size());

            } else {
                try {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + 
response.errorBody().string());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                List<Model> models = response.body();

                for (Model model : models) {
                    textView.append(model.getAlbumId() + "\n");
                    textView.append(model.getId()+"\n");
                    textView.append(model.getTitle()+"\n");
                    textView.append(model.getUrl()+"\n");
                    textView.append(model.getThumbnailUrl()+"\n");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Model>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("tes2", "onFailure: " + t);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: что значит одного блока? вы можете показать весь ответ?

Comment: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos

Comment: Не очень понятно - Вы хотите чтобы сервер прислал один объект и получить его? Или не знаете как взять один объект из уже полученного списка? С этим конкретным API возможны оба варианта.

Comment: Не знаю как взять один объект из уже полученного списка

Comment: Тогда манипуляции с URL здесь не при чём.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Model> models = response.body();

// получаем один элемент по индексу в списке,
// где index - номер элемента в списке (считается с 0)
Model model = models.get(index);
```

---

```
// если нужно взять элемент по id или другому параметру
// тогда ищем с помощью цикла, myId - нужное значение
Model model = null;
for (Model m : models) {
    if (m.getId() == myId) {
        model = m;
        break;
    }
}
if (model == null) {
    // не найдено
} else {
```

---

```
// используем
textView.append(model.getAlbumId() + "\n");
textView.append(model.getId()+"\n");
textView.append(model.getTitle()+"\n");
textView.append(model.getUrl()+"\n");
textView.append(model.getThumbnailUrl()+"\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

В ответе сервера содержиться массив с вашими альбомами, поэтому вам нужно сделать сначала один класс_модель_1, а потом сделать класс_модель_2 который содержить архив состоящий из класс_модель_1. Вот например:

```
public class AlbumModel {
    @SerializedName("albumId")
    @Expose
    private int albumId;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("url")
    private String url;
    @SerializedName("thumbnailUrl")
    @Expose
    private String thumbnailUrl;

     // здесь вам нужно разместить все геттеры и сеттеры этих полей
}
```

дальше вам нужно получать массив:

```
public class AlbumArray {
    @SerializedName("albums")
    @Expose
    private List<AlbumModel> albums= null;

    public AlbumArray() {
    }



    public List<AlbumModel> getAlbums() {
        return albums;
    }
}
```

и дальше в интерфейсе вам нужно использовать класс `AlbumArray` и получать список ваших альбомов при удачном запросе. Только меня немного смутило отсутствие наименования массива, если у вас есть возможность каким-то образом назвать ваш массив чтобы в json это название было, то было бы неплохо так как на этом держиться класс модель.

P.S. Я бы на вашем месте дополнил вопрос фрагментом json ответа, чтобы другие пользователи могли с ним ознакомится и тоже дать ответ.

Comment: не обязательно создавать класс для хранения списка классов.

Comment: а как еще можно? я у себя просто так в проекте делал, и по другому не знаю как еще можно :)

Comment: @GET("v1/semesters")
    Single<List<Semester>> getSemesters();